# Who uses the `UserUnit` property in PDF?

Tags: pdf

I am working on a PDF library which uses the `UserUnit` property in some computations. I would like to test the library on real data but I cannot find any real-world PDF documents with non-standard `UserUnit`. What are the use cases for this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need `UserUnit` if you want to specify a `MediaSize` in excess of (IIRC) 1440 points (200 inches) in either dimension.

Note that this is an **Acrobat** limitation, it can't handle `MediaSize` values larger than that, other applications can. If you want a `MediaSize` exceeding that, and you expect your file to view in Acrobat, you need to set `UserUnit`.

I do have real world files which set `UserUnit` (very, very few) but cannot share them as they are customer files. I'm told that these are used for architectural plans, apparently some regulatory bodies require **all** the plans to be on a single 'sheet', the only way to do that with (for example) a multi-story building is to have a very large 'sheet'.

Comment: Can confirm, this is an extremely rare to be used in practice, and I too have no real world examples that I can offer. Fortunately the only effect it has is on the "physical" dimensions. So for interactive viewing this just affects the zoom level. When printing, or converting to an image (Image DPI metadata should reflect this value), this would be taken into account.